# EntityFramework sorting related entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following query which works fine

```
        var x = cc.Products
                    .Include("Category")
                    .Include("Supplier")
                    .Include("Manufacturer")
                    .Include("ProductPrices")
                    .Include("ProductPrices.Valuta")
                    .Include("ProductPrices.UnitOfMeasure")
                    .OrderBy(p => p.PartNumber);
```

I'm not trying to sort the ProductPrices descending so I can select the latest price. However I can't get it into a single query. Essentially I only need to select one of the ProductPrices based on the Id of that column.

Is there any way to do this? Or should I first evaluate the query, then ForEach them and Sort the navigation property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a delegate method in your orderby clause:

```
var x = cc.Products
                    .Include("Category")
                    .Include("Supplier")
                    .Include("Manufacturer")
                    .Include("ProductPrices")
                    .Include("ProductPrices.Valuta")
                    .Include("ProductPrices.UnitOfMeasure")
                    .OrderBy(delegate (Product p) {
                          //some logic here
                          //order by the greatest price
                          // e.g:
                          return p.ProductPrices.Max(i => i.Price);
                    });
```

Comment: This sorts all my products based on the price, I'm trying to sort my related entity collection for each product. Products itself are sorted by PartNumber